# How to set new bridges for tor?

Tags: tor

I installed tor by `sudo apt-get install tor` and get 3 following bridges via email:

```
obfs4 37.218.246.221:39337 79357DD63FD91089513B4E58E7B7066A3E8558CC cert=VM5mFtvtLLyCMw3M0vmd/T5lytxJrJre59RjxT+2U2zv1ZhjvVo3TksbEQReco9aNw8dbg iat-mode=0
  obfs4 194.132.208.99:27832 7133823DAFAA2461D15AABA2CB02F15ED66B1477 cert=MoSy4wBUhFswtqtfq8HlC06i9rny4+a5wP6CblKCbDtzn2lEwlaxVF+4fFoOMW92nVlVcw iat-mode=0
  obfs4 192.210.192.101:52249 17DDDE22E494F3BF14E5FB01165F28FEDE7EEC9C cert=0TJYrc07J6jSMjk8WVLuGGTmEKm3BYkYxE07nZLvwsnBF47kUMxwoH3ECxUDkIRptuHzDA iat-mode=0
```

Tried to append them to `/etc/tor/torrc`, but when i want to restart tor, it cant and has some problem?
How can I use them? Don't want to use tor-browser, I want to use `torify` in terminal!

I also have some problem about googling about this problem because related topics are blocked in my area.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More details = more help.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you asked this some time ago, but try to add the following code in your /etc/tor/torrc file:

```
UseBridges 1
```

This will activate the use of bridges. I had this very problem recently, I added this command in the tor config file and it started using bridges again.

Try it.