# Adding bridges in torrc

Tags: proxy, tor

My college recently blacklisted tor traffic, which was my only connection to the sites I regularly use, and I would rather not use tor browser. I cannot add bridges to the `/etc/tor/torrc` file.

I have followed all the steps in the thread:
[How to set new bridges for tor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712869/how-to-set-new-bridges-for-tor)

obfsproxy is definitely installed

I have added them in the format:

```
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3, scamblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
Bridge obfs3 <162.243.5.40:36325> <1422EFD2258405A257265F5A098F85C3144E1118>
```

and in the format:

```
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3, scamblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
Bridge obfs3 162.243.5.40:36325 1422EFD2258405A257265F5A098F85C3144E1118
```

After I restart or reload tor it comes up with the error

It works when I add `UseBridged 0`
but as soon as I add:

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3, scamblesuit exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
```

or

```
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /usr/bin/obfsproxy managed
```

The following error message is displayed:

```
Job for tor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: tor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: tor.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: Stopped Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: tor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: Failed to start Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: tor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 01 15:22:18 P systemd[1]: tor.service: Failed with result 'start-limit'.
```

When I # out the added lines it runs fine, and I can run connections through the proxy on a different network. Am I missing something obvious or has the format changed?